# Attempting to call execvp to run programname supplied through stdin, but call fails each time

Tags: c, fork, parent-child, execvp

Good evening

I have found a few similar questions, but nothing that suffices based on this specific question.

I am forking a child process, and attempting to call execvp to run a simple program which outputs 3 chars to stdout. The program name to be run comes from user input.

For some reason every call to execvp fails for simpleO:

I compile file simpleO.c into simpleO, and then compile and run fork.c. I type simpleO into the prompt when requested to attempt to run, but each time I get the error. Here is the code.

The error message printed by perror is "No such file or directory"

--

fork.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>/*fork, exec*/
#include <errno.h>/*errno*/
#include <string.h> /*strerror*/
#include <stdlib.h>/*EXIT_FAILURE*/

#define BUFFERSIZE 100

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int i = 0;
pid_t pid;
int status;
char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];

fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin);

argv[0] = strtok(buffer, " ");
while (buffer[i] != '\0') {/*analyze each char*/
    if (buffer[i] == ' ')/*based on how many spaces there are*/
        argv[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");/*tokenize, populate argv*/
    i++;
}  

if((pid = fork()) == -1){
    fprintf(stderr, "fork error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;}
else if (pid==0) {
    int e = execvp(argv[0],argv);
    if (e==-1) {
        perror("Exec failed");
        printf("Process %s\n",argv[0]);
        perror("Process did not run");
        exit(1);
    }
}
else{
    wait(&status);}
return 0;
}
```

--

simpleO.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    printf("%c",'c');
    printf("%c",'2');
    printf("%c",'1');
return 0;
}
```

Addl ref: perror prints "No such file or directory"

Comment: Same problem occurs typing ./simpleO

Comment: You could helpfully add the message printed by `perror` so that those of us without psychic powers can see what you see.

Comment: Updated for muggles

Comment: Can you please ensure your code compiles before posting? `array_of_pointers` is undeclared for example.

Comment: Updated because I'm a muggle and forgot to remove array_of_pointers

Comment: Also, that `while` loop is just gibberish. Where is `i` declared and initialized? Why do you think its value in any way influences the call to `strtok`? And what makes you think `argv` is big enough to hold all the words in your input line, even assuming you manage to split them out?

Comment: Good questions. I didn't copy and paste the entire code so there were a few discrepancies. It should compile ok now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, look: a key lesson in programming is that *when an error message tells you something, you should believe it*.  So, your program is saying "no such file or directory", and it means the file you're trying to run doesn't exist at whatever path you're trying to use.

You now know that it's not at the default path, so the next thing to try is to use the *absolute path* of the executable. Now, given the rest of this, I'd suggest you write a very simple C program that does nothing whatsoever besides trying to fork/exec your child program. No `argv` vector or anything, just `fork` and then `execvp` in the child with the executable path an absolute parth.

Comment: ***BINGO!***
Now you know the problem.  Here's your next step: use `getcwd()` and find out what the *real* current directory is.  then you can either use `setcwd()` to change to what you *think* the current directory should be, or you can figure out how to compute the appropriate path without hardcoding it.

Comment: Ah and then strcat /programname onto the end of that absolute path?

Thanks for response btw

Comment: "_A key lesson in programming is that when an error message tells you something, you should believe it._" Gonna make my students learn this by heart and recite at the beginning and end of each class...

Comment: Wow I think I found it. There was a newline (from fgets()) at the end of my buffer and it was screwing up the absolute path. Many thanks Charlie!

Comment: "A key lesson in programming is that when an error message tells you something, you should believe it." 

Indeed. Simply had to delete the / at the end of the absolute path. D'oh!

Comment: @DYZ, it is positively amazing how often I have to give this lesson to baby programmers, and even some pretty experienced programmers.

Another one of these  lessons is that the probability is > 0.995 that it is *not* a compiler bug.

Comment: @ian_wytiam, you're welcome and don't fret about it. Some time I'll tell you about the time I spent two days trying to figure out why changes I made weren't affecting the program results before I realized it wasn't compiling and the library system was just using the old executable. (This was in punchcard days.)